# Python Django: Emailing xlsxwriter with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, django, pandas, xlsxwriter

I had an old script that pulled some data and manually wrote each line to an excel file in xlsxwriter and followed up by emailing that information.

I thought it would be more efficient and easier to make changes if it were in a pandas dataframe. I can't seem to get the file to attach and send as I did in the past. It's now returning this error: `Error: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>`

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
views.py
def download(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="slotDownload.xlsx"'
    writer = Write2Excel(FloorTracker.objects.filter(on_floor=1).select_related('user').select_related('showroom_number'),request)
    response.write(writer)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/slotUploader/')

def WriteToExcel(data, request):
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
    header = workbook.add_format({
        'color': 'black',
        'align': 'center',
    })
    dateformat = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/dd/yyyy'})
    worksheet_s = workbook.add_worksheet("download") # add worksheet_s

    #Write column headers
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,0, 'Showroom Number', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,1, 'Brand', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,2, 'Family', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,3, 'Mattress', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,4, 'On Floor', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,5, 'Size', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,6, 'Underbed', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,7, 'lastUpdate', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,8, 'Rep', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,9, 'NAM', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,10, 'City', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,11, 'State', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,12, 'Warehouse Name', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,13, 'Value Zone', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,14, 'Comparison Center', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,15, 'Suggested Retail', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,16, 'Showroom Name', header)
    worksheet_s.write_string(0,17, 'Company', header)

    for idx, item in enumerate(data):
        row = 1 + idx
        worksheet_s.write_string(row, 0, item.showroom_number.storenumber)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row, 1, item.brand)
        worksheet_s.write(row, 2, item.family)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row, 3, item.mattress)
        worksheet_s.write(row, 4, item.on_floor)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row, 5, item.size)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row, 6, item.underbed)
        worksheet_s.write_datetime(row, 7, datetime.strptime(item.lastupdate, '%Y-%m-%d'), dateformat)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row,8, item.user.username)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row,9, item.showroom_number.nam.username)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row,10, item.showroom_number.city)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row,11, item.showroom_number.state)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row,12, item.showroom_number.warehouseName.Warehouse_Name)
        worksheet_s.write(row,13, 0 if not item.in_vzone else 1)
        worksheet_s.write(row,14, 0 if not item.in_comparison else 1)
        worksheet_s.write(row,15, item.suggested_retail)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row,16, item.showroom_number.storename)
        worksheet_s.write_string(row,17, item.company)

    workbook.close()
    sendEmailWithAttach(request,request.user.email,output)

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def sendEmailWithAttach(request, emailto, output):
    html_content = "Here is your most updated slot information. \n Thanks! \n Rich"
    email = EmailMessage("Slot Uploader Data", html_content, "rich.wolff@tempursealy.com", [emailto])
    email.content_subtype = "html"
    email.attach('slotUploader.xlsx', output.getvalue(), 'application/vnd.ms-excel')
    try:
        res = email.send()
    except:
        import sys
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print('Error: %s' % e)
        res = e

    return HttpResponse('%s'%res)
```

Here is the code after the changes with the error `Error: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>`:

```
views.py
def download(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="slotDownload.xlsx"'
    writer = Write2Excel(FloorTracker.objects.filter(on_floor=1).select_related('user').select_related('showroom_number'),request)
    response.write(writer)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/slotUploader/')

def Write2Excel(data, request):
    output = StringIO.StringIO()
    ddf = read_frame(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(ddf)
    del df['sugg_retail']
    del df['id']
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.close()
    sendEmailWithAttach(request,request.user.email,output)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def sendEmailWithAttach(request, emailto, output):
    html_content = "Here is your most updated slot information. \n Thanks! \n Rich"
    email = EmailMessage("Slot Uploader Data", html_content, "rich.wolff@tempursealy.com", [emailto])
    email.content_subtype = "html"
    email.attach('slotUploader.xlsx', output, 'application/vnd.ms-excel')
    try:
        res = email.send()
    except:
        import sys
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print('Error: %s' % e)
        res = e

    return HttpResponse('%s'%res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem on your second code is at `email.attach('slotUploader.xlsx', output, 'application/vnd.ms-excel')` ... It should be `output.getValue()`